# Contractible fibers implies $H^*(E) \cong H^*(B)$ for $p:E \rightarrow B$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

I believe the following is true:

> Let $F\rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle. If $F$ is contractible, then $H^*(E;R) \cong H^*(B;R)$ for a commutative ring $R$ with identity.

I will apply [Theorem 4D.1, Hatcher's](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf). There are two conditions to check.

(a) $H^n(F;R)$ is f.g. free $R$-module for all $n$ - which is trivially true.

(b) that there exists classes $c \in H^k(E;R)$ such that $i^*(c)$ generates $H^*(F;R)$ for each fiber.

But this follows as $$i^*: H^*(E;R) \rightarrow H^*(F;R) \cong R $$
is a ring homomorphism, mapping $1$ to $1$.

---

The result of theorem states that $H^*(B;R) \otimes_R R \rightarrow H^*(E;R)$ is an isomorphism of groups.

---

**Is the statement true, and is my proof correct? Are there any details that I may have missed?**

Comment: Use the long-exact homotopy sequence of the bundle to see that $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a weak equivalence. Then simply observe that singular homology is invariant under weak equivalence.

Comment: As for your question, I think there is a typo in your statement. Your proof is correct. Note that the formula Hatcher gives for the group isomorphism reduces to the induced map $p^*$ in the case that $c_i=1$.

Comment: Seems perfectly good to me by Leray-Hirsch.

Comment: @Tyrone, thanks for pointing out.